# Problema al enviar parametros de android a php

Tags: php, android-studio, android-volley

tengo un problema con mi aplicación android al momento de enviar parametros con volley, tengo que mostrar los datos de un usuario que inició sesión en mi app, los datos están en un servidor, en mi php los regreso con Json, funciona muy bien cuando los envio con parametros en el php, pero en el getParams de volley no envia los valores de mis variables globales.

adjunto codigo:

**EDIT DE MAIN LISTA:**

MainLista.java aqui leo el Json

```
public class MainLista extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txt1;
    ListView listaPerfil;

    String LINK = "https://viavel.com.mx/pruebas/PHPRicardo/ejemplomostrar.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_lista);
        listaPerfil = findViewById(R.id.listaPerfil);

        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        llamadovolley();
    }

    private void llamadovolley() {

        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LINK, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<>();
                params.put("email", Globales.USER_EMAIL);
                params.put("contrasena", Globales.USER_PASS);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rq.add(sr);
    }
}
```

Archivo php:

```
    session_start();
    include('Conexion2.php');

    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $pass   = $_POST['contrasena'];

    $sql="SELECT c.nombre, c.apellido, c.telefono1, c.email, c.fechanacimiento, c.contrasena, f.imagen
            FROM clientes AS c
            INNER JOIN fotos AS f ON c.clienteid = f.clienteid
            WHERE c.email = '$email' AND c.contrasena = '$pass'";

$pdo = pdo();
$query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$query -> execute(array($cons));
$res = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($res);

echo $json;
 ?>
```

Este el json que obtengo del php cuando le pongo datos fijos en el query:

```
[{"nombre":"Fernando","apellido":"Villarreal","telefono1":"8672554040","email":"ricardito@gmail.com","fechanacimiento":"2021-02-11","contrasena":"12345678","imagen":"https:**********/FP-aYRsz-891.png"}]
```

Mainlista muestra un objeto de una lista, el error que me sale en php es Undefined index en la linea 5 y 6 del php.
Espero puedan ayudarme, que tengan buen dia

Comment: ¿Qué hace actualmente tu código? ¿Has depurado algo? ¿Con qué resultados? Una cosa que me parece rara es que uses Volley y AsyncTask juntas, ¿a qué se debe eso?

Comment: Hola Ricardo si los regresas con json agrega un ejemplo de como se regresan, es decir que obtienes en echo $json;

Comment: @A.Cedano Mi codigo solo muestra una pantalla en blanco, cuando el en php en lugar de poner las variables en el query pongo datos fijos, me muestra los datos que deberia con el formato que le di, lo del volley y Async, es porque fue la forma que encontre de hacerlo, soy principiante

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo eh añadido a la publicacion

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema viene de esa mezcla. O usas Volley o usas AsyncTask. Tú estás pasando por Volley para luego mandar la petición con AsyncTask. Eso no tiene ningún sentido. Volley es una librería completa para hacer peticiones remotas. Revisa la documentación de Android y algunos ejemplos aquí mismo que indican cómo mandar parámetros con Volley.

Comment: @A.Cedano como podria hacer para que volley me envie los parametros y luego leerlos con AsyncTask?

Comment: Como ya dije antes, son dos cosas distintas. Volley hace con ventaja lo que AsyncTask hace. Además, AsyncTask fue declarada obsoleta en la API 30, por lo que deberías dejar de usarla. Si usas Volley, **en el `onResponse` tendrás los datos de la respuesta y podrás leerlos allí mismo, o sea, no necesitas AsyncTask para leer lo que te trae Volley, es algo absurdo...**. Prueba por tanto a implementar Volley, quitando todo lo referente a AsyncTask y si tienes algún problema preguntas por aquí. Como está el código con esa mezcla de cosas no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano entendido, ya eh quitado todo lo de AsyncTask, y si ah enviado los parametros a php, ya solo queda parsear el json que obtengo de respuesta

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para poner el código como lo tienes ahora. Si ya tienes la respuesta es relativamente fácil leer los datos. Para este caso necesitarías crear un JSONArray, acceder a la clave `0` del mismo y obtener el JSONObject que hay dentro. Si esperas un solo dato sería más simple modificar la respuesta en el servidor, pero ese es otro asunto que no viene al caso ahora.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120441/discussion-between-ricardo-villanueva-and-a-cedano).